# Qt связь между классами

Tags: c++, qt, классы

Ребята, помогите пожалуйста, есть класс который рисует картинку в зависимости от `QSlider`-ов другого класса. Все работает, все супер, но есть необходимость чтобы были `RadioButton`-ы на который нажимаешь и вместо этого класса в `Layout` включался другой класс с другой картинкой и наоборот. В общем, нужно что бы по нажатии `RadioButton`-a переключались классы, которые отображают картинку, чем-то отдаленно похоже на MDI приложение.

Comment: QStackedWidget добавьте в него  виджеты для отображения картинок

Comment: Александр, спасибо большое за ответ)